# "I saw him crossing" vs. "I saw him cross"

Tags: present-participles, gerund-vs-infinitive, ing, sense-verbs

> I saw him crossing the road.
>   I saw him cross the road.

Which one is correct and why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They are both correct, grammatically speaking. However, they have slightly different meanings.

> I saw him crossing the road.

... suggests that you saw a male person in the middle of crossing the road (he was probably walking in the middle of the road toward one of the sides). But, you didn't *necessarily* see him get to the side of the road

> I saw him cross the road.

... suggests that you saw him do the entire action of starting on one side, walking across, and ending up on the other side.

Comment: I was just in the process of writing almost the exact same thing when you posted yours.  :-)

Comment: Is the 'to scross the road' the object of 'saw'? or the complement of 'him'?

Comment: @snooze Yes, it is the object of saw. This construct is know as *complex object*.